# Why additional classes doesn't work with fontawesome?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have a question. Do any of you know why when a try to add an additional class to a fontawesome icon it doesn't work?? Looks like this,

```html
<i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>.
```

What I want to do is to add an additional class to this item just like `.hide.` 
It should work this way

```html
<i class="fas fa-angle-up hide></i>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: You must edit the question because it is mixed with the code example that was added, for when you want to show code the best way is to use a Code Snippet

Comment: Are you missing the closing `"` after `hide` in your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if it is possible to put additional classes to a fontawesome icon, it is usually like this:

```
<i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
```

And you only add the additional classes you need, these must be previously created:

```
<i class="fas fa-angle-up hide"></i>
```